# Gauss's Law over two non-symmetric surfaces

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, conductors, boundary-conditions

Let's say I have a sphere conductor with an electric charge $q$ and radius $R$. The sphere is inserted between two spaces: one material with relative permissivity $\epsilon$ (below) and the other is a vacuum $\epsilon_0$ (above). Like in the image below. I'm asked to find the charge in each hemisphere in contact with the surfaces.

I checked the resolution to this problem and didn't quite understand. Why am I able to do Gauss Law over the chosen surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$? I thought it was supposed to have symmetry such that $\vec{E} = \vec{E(r)}$. Being a hemisphere it doesn't have symmetry, or does it?

[image]

Comment: "symmetry such that $\vec{E} = \vec{E(r)}$."  That makes no sense, so you need to _edit your question_.  Do you mean that $\vec E$ is supposed to be _parallel_ to a radius?  I.e. $\vec E = E \hat r$, where $E$ is the scalar electric field strength and $\hat r$ is the unit vector in the direction of the radius?

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that this is a conductor so the surface of the conductor will be an equipotential.  Thus, as there is no charge inside your conductor, solving Poisson's equation $-\nabla^2 V=0$ in the upper or lower half of your diagram should be done in spherical coordinates since $V$ itself is spherically symmetric, resulting in a $\vec E$ field with spherical symmetry in either half, although the $\vec E$ field will not have the same magnitude in both media.

This radial symmetry of $\vec E$ is what makes Gauss' law useful: even if the field is not the same in both media, it is *radial* in both media.

Answer (score -1):

Gauss law is valid for any surface that is closed, you can close each hemisphere individually and apply gauss law, it has nothing to do with symmetry

Comment: Sorry while Gauss’ law always holds, one can *rarely* reconstruct the $\vec E$ field *unless* the field is symmetric.